# How to rank sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a set of results that I want to rank:

I am not sure what to partition by.

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    TFormSectionID AS FormSectionID, 
    TFSSortOrder AS SectionSortOrder, 
    TSectionItemID AS SectionItemID, TrendType
FROM            
    Report.TrendData
WHERE        
    (ProgramID = 1) 
    AND (TrendType > 0) 
    AND tformid = 34 
    AND TFormSectionID = 12
```

Results:

```
FormSectionID   SectionSortOrder    SectionItemID   TrendType
    12                 7                  90            1
    12                 7                  91            1
    12                 7                  154           1
    12                 7                  528           1
    12                 9                  154           1
    12                 9                  528           1
```

I want the results with section sort order 9 to be ranked as 2 and the section sort order 7 to be ranked as 1

Comment: you partition by sectionsortorder

Comment: What is the logic for why you want the results you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you can get what you want using `DENSE_RANK`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TFormSectionID AS FormSectionID, 
       TFSSortOrder AS SectionSortOrder, 
       TSectionItemID AS SectionItemID, 
       TrendType,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SectionSortOrder) AS rn       
FROM Report.TrendData
WHERE (ProgramID = 1) AND (TrendType > 0) AND 
      tformid = 34 and TFormSectionID = 12
```

Comment: Elaborating a bit: window function don't *require* a partitioning clause.  Without one, it simply uses the whole result set as the partition.